# 2 массива и foreach

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть 2 массива

```
$categories = get_categories($args);

$game_query = get_posts($post_args);
```

$categories - список категорий

$game_query - список постов

Есть вот такой вот цикл который выводит категории и каждые 5 блоков с категориями вставляет div "rand_game"

```
$counter = 0;

foreach (array_chunk($categories, 2) as $cat_block) { 
  $counter++;

  if ($counter %5 == 0) {
    ?>
      <div class="rand_game">

      </div> 
    <?php
  }
  ?>
  <div class="cat_block">
    <?php foreach ($cat_block as $cat_item) {
    ?>
      <div class="cat_item">
          <div class="category_text">
            <p><?php echo $cat_item->name; ?></p>
          </div>
      </div>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
  </div>
  <?php
}
```

Так вот нужно в div "rand_game" вывести значения из массива со списком постов, например вывести post_title. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Всем спасибо, задача решена, нужно было добавить пару строк кода. Работающий скрипт, может кому нибудь понадобится:

```
$counter = 0;
$index = 0; 

foreach (array_chunk($categories, 2) as $cat_block) { 
  $counter++;

  if ($counter %5 == 0) {

    $title = $game_query[$index]->post_title;
    $index++;

    ?>
      <div class="rand_game">
        <?php echo $title;?>
      </div> 
    <?php
  }
  ?>
  <div class="cat_block">
    <?php foreach ($cat_block as $cat_item) {
    ?>
      <div class="cat_item">
          <div class="category_text">
            <p><?php echo $cat_item->name; ?></p>
          </div>
      </div>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
  </div>
  <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Что-то страшное вы там делаете.

Comment: Задача была такая, нужно вывести список всех категорий по 2 категории в div 'cat_block', через каждые 5 '.cat_block' нужно вывести div. '.rand_game' с одним постом. пример как это выглядит можно посмотреть http://onlineguru.ru/, только там не через каждые 5, но схема понятна. Я не проффесионал в php, написал как смог) Если Вы сможете дать пару советов как улучшить этот скрипт, я буду очень рад, спасибо.